# Unable to get GraphAware to run on Windows Community edition

Tags: plugins, neo4j, graphaware

I've tried installing and running from the Zip instead of EXE as other have mentioned.

Gives a 404 if authorization header is supplied, and 401 if not

GraphAware seems to have only a version for 2.2.2, whereas 2.2.3 is the latest on the neo4j site. Managed to track down 2.2.2 only to have it not work still. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

It is correct the GraphAware modules are not compatible with Neo4j2.2.3 due to a bug in the Transaction data in neo4j itself (ref here https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/4910) which should be fixed in 2.2.4 or 2.3-RC1

If you installed via the zip, this should however work with 2.2.2,  Please amend your question with the modules you use and their version, also all configuration you have set for the moduleS.

Comment: I'm using graphaware-server-community-all-2.2.2.32.jar in the plugins folder of Neo4j 2.2.2, all other settings are default. Everything I've read says you should just drop this in the plugins folder and it should just work.  Let me know specifically what you're looking for if this is not it, I'm fairly new working with neo4j

Comment: What URL are you trying to access that gives you 404? The framework itself does not provide an API, you need at least one module to go with it.